# Как по простому настраивать вид графиков в R?

Tags: r, график

Правильно ли я понимаю, что для получения графиков в R с нужным масштабом, требуемым форматом чисел т.д., и т.д. (т.е. качественных и красивых, как в других стат. программах) нужно писать и писать коды, всё прописывать детально на низком уровне ...? В противном случае графики выглядят явно кустарно, не для статьи!

P.S. Кустарный (в сравнении с обычными стат. программами) вид графиков в R (даже приводимых в публикациях) меня обескуражил...

Может, есть пакет, реализующий интерактивный режим?

Comment: `нужно писать и писать коды, всё прописывать`

Шок! На языке программирования нужно писать код!

Comment: Kromster, спасибо за правку! :)

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, есть довольно много бесплатных библиотек, которые уже преднастроены для красивых графиков, которые можно публиковать в книжках, в большинстве своем они основаны на ggplot2. Так, что можно обойтись и без программирования. Скажем, посетите сайт марсельца Абдукаделя Касамбара:

- **[factoextra](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factoextra-r-package-easy-multivariate-data-analyses-and-elegant-visualization)** (работа с PCA, CA, MCA, MFA, HMFA);
- **[survminer](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survminer-r-package-survival-data-analysis-and-visualization)** (графики по анализу выживания);
- **[ggpubr](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots)** (просто удобное расширение ggplot2).
- **[ggcorrplot](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggcorrplot-visualization-of-a-correlation-matrix-using-ggplot2)** (один из вариантов работы с корреляционным матрицами)

Но есть куча других и они постоянно прибывают. Тут важно знание английского языка и возможность читать например, довольно старый обзор, но начинать нужно с него [CRAN Task View: Graphic Displays & Dynamic Graphics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Graphics.html) и конечно  [the R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/).

Мне лично нравиться весьма простой, но очень информативный набор график для отбора теоретических распределений для эмпирического вектора данных - [Подбор дискретных и непрерывных распределений](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/distributions/fitting.html).

Comment: Александр, большое спасибо за столь обстоятельный ответ! :)

Answer (score 1):

На ggplot можно, конечно, сделать почти что угодно, в том числе и в оформлении, но он совсем не прост в освоении. Помогают примеры и stackoverflow.

Но я так понимаю, что вам вообще не хочется тратить время на освоение графических библиотек, но при этом использовать R для расчетов. Посмотрите, возможно, [exploratory](https://exploratory.io/features/visualization) вам понравится.

Comment: Arcady, Большое Спасибо! Вы поняли, что я "хотела знать, но спросить боялись" :)